# Rock-Paper-Scissors game

Tags: c++, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

This is the first piece of code I wrote on my own.  I tried to use everything I know, like functions, loops and variables.  Is it good or could it be simpler?

Please be hard as you can be with me because I feel my programming knowledge is quite poor and I end up using Google for solving my problems.

```
    // RPS.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int nPlayerScore=0;
int nComputerScore=0;
int nPlayerMove=0;
int nComputerMove=0;

void DisplayScore()
{
    cout << "Player: " << nPlayerScore << endl;
    cout << "Computer: " << nComputerScore << endl << endl;
}

int GetMove()
{
    cout << "Please choose a move: \n1.Rock\n2.Paper\n3.Scissors\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    return x;
}

void CalculateResults()
{
    if (nPlayerMove==1) //player is Rock
    {
        if (nComputerMove==1) {cout << "player Rock vs computer Rock: IT'S A TIE!";}
        if (nComputerMove==2) {cout << "player Rock vs computer Paper: COMPUTER WON!"; nComputerScore=nComputerScore+1;}
        if (nComputerMove==3) {cout << "player Rock vs computer Scissors: PLAYER WON!"; nPlayerScore=nPlayerScore+1;}
    }
    if (nPlayerMove==2) //player is Paper
    {
        if (nComputerMove==1) {cout << "player Paper vs computer Rock: PLAYER WON!"; nPlayerScore=nPlayerScore+1;}
        if (nComputerMove==2) {cout << "player Paper vs computer Paper: IT'S A TIE!";}
        if (nComputerMove==3) {cout << "player Paper vs computer Scissors: COMPUTER WON!"; nComputerScore=nComputerScore+1;}
    }
    if (nPlayerMove==3) //player is Scissors
    {
        if (nComputerMove==1) {cout << "player Scissors vs computer Rock: COMPUTER WON!"; nComputerScore=nComputerScore+1;}
        if (nComputerMove==2) {cout << "player Scissors vs computer Paper: PLAYER WON!"; nPlayerScore=nPlayerScore+1;}
        if (nComputerMove==3) {cout << "player Scissors vs computer Scissors: IT'S A TIE!";}
    }

cout << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    do
    {
    cout << "Welcome to RPS 1.0a \tby GeTAFIX \n\n";
    DisplayScore();
    nPlayerMove=GetMove();
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    nComputerMove=rand()%(3)+1;
    CalculateResults();
    //cout << "Press any key to continue...";
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    } while (1==1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, stop using `system("pause");` and `system("cls");`.  Both of those are not portable, and are silly ways of achieving what you want.  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1173208/559931) for an actual solution.

Secondly, you are seeding the random number generator every iteration.  This is not only unnecessary, it is harmful: if you do this in a program that calls `rand` more than once a second, you will get the same result each call.  Even if you are only accessing it once a second (as you may be here), it is bad practice in any case, and can lead to a decrease in randomness.

Thirdly, I think you're getting a little far with splitting things into functions.  It might make sense to split the move-reading part into a separate function if you're going to perform input validation, but I think it currently just complicates matters.

Your `CalculateResults` function is overcomplicated.  If 0 is rock, 1 is paper, and 2 is scissors, and `x` and `y` are the choices of the players, you can tell who won with `(3+x-y)%3`.  If the result is 1 then `x` has won; if it is 2, then `y` has won; otherwise (if it is 0) there has been a tie.

Further stylistic issues: you should fix your indentation, turn the `do ... while` loop into a `while(true)` or `for(;;)` loop, stop using `using namespace std;`, and disable precompiled headers (they offer no benefit for a single-file solution).  You should also output `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` unless you explicitly want to flush the stream; an expression like `std::cout << std::endl << std::endl` simply doesn't make sense.

By the way, if you're using Google to solve your C++ problems, you're likely picking up a lot of information that's very wrong.  Make sure you have a good book to learn from, such as [Accelerated C++](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020170353X).

Your code could be simplified to this, although the behaviour isn't quite the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string numberToWeapon(int n) {
    switch (n) {
       case 0: return "rock";
       case 1: return "paper";
       case 2: return "scissors";
    }
    assert(!"Invalid parameter");
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Rock-Paper-Scissors v1.0\n";

    int playerScore = 0;
    int ourScore = 0;
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    while (true) {
         int playerMove;
         std::cout << "Please enter 1 for rock, 2 for paper, or 3 for scissors.\n";
         if (!(std::cin >> playerMove))
             return 0;
         --playerMove;
         if (playerMove < 0 || playerMove > 2) {
             std::cout << "Invalid input.\n";
             continue;
         }

         int ourMove = rand()%3;

         std::cout << "You played: " << numberToWeapon(playerMove) << ". ";
         std::cout << "We played: " << numberToWeapon(ourMove) << ".\n";
         switch ((3 + playerMove - ourMove) % 3) {
             case 0:
                 std::cout << "The game is a tie.\n";
                 break;
             case 1:
                 std::cout << "You won!\n";
                 ++playerScore;
                 break;
             case 2:
                 std::cout << "We won!\n";
                 ++ourScore;
                 break;
         }

         std::cout << "The score is currently:\n";
         std::cout << "You - " << playerScore << ".\n";
         std::cout << "We - " << ourScore << ".\n";
    }
}
```

This results in a larger `main` function, but no global variables.  You can argue on whether that's any better or not: personally, I think it's clear as it is, and I don't see any duplication, but you may want to experiment.

If you are using C++11, you can get even more awesome syntax than the `numberToWeapon` function, namely:

```
std::array<4, std::string> weapons = {"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
```

And then use `weapons.at(num)` (or `weapons[num]` if you're sure you're in-bounds).

Comment: I would note that re-seeding the rand even every second is still bad and leads to non random numbers.

Comment: thank you for all the critic, I like the code and your thought process and hope I can learn thinking in code like that soon... I also wanna go to school for either computer science or software engineering but still a little afraid i won't be disciplined about my codes and have a good struct thinking process of how to build it

Comment: @johnsmith: Your code is not particularly bad; most of your errors may simply be a matter of not getting good information.  The fact that you're asking for code reviews is already a good sign, and I advise you follow that path if you think it would be enjoyable.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with most of what Anton already mentioned:

In addition:

```
 using namespace std;
```

Stop using this.
It works out great for small programs but for large programs it becomes more of a problem. Getting in to the habit of **not** using it.

I would avoid over use of std::endl everywhere. What it does is place a newline character then flush the stream. If you have lots of output then it will cause the output to perform sub-optimally.

```
cout << "Player: " << nPlayerScore << endl;
cout << "Computer: " << nComputerScore << endl << endl;
```

In this case change two of the std::endl into "\n". Then use the last one to flush the output to the screen.

Good start but you should validate the input.
What If I typed Rock instead of 1. Then the stream gets broken and all further input is ignored. So validate your input and fix the stream if the bad bit is set.

```
int GetMove()
{
    cout << "Please choose a move: \n1.Rock\n2.Paper\n3.Scissors\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    return x;
}
```

In this function:

```
void CalculateResults()
```

There are a lot of repeating strings. Anton suggested using functions to solve this. I think that is overkill for this situation and would just set up an array of strings.

```
static std::string  weapon[]    = { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };
static std::string  result[3][] = {{ "IT'S A TIE!",   "COMPUTER WON!", "PLAYER WON!"  },
                                   { "PLAYER WON!",   "IT'S A TIE!",   "COMPUTER WON!"},
                                   { "COMPUTER WON!", "PLAYER WON!",   "IT'S A TIE!"  }
                                  };
```

Now you can easily display the weapons with:

```
std::cout << "player "   << weapon[nPlayerMove-1]
          << " Vs "
          << "computer " << weapon[nComputerMove-1]
          << "  "        << result[nPlayerMove-1][nComputerMove-1];
```

Lat of all:

```
cout << "Welcome to RPS 1.0a \tby GeTAFIX \n\n";
```

Here I would have used std::endl just to force a flush. Because the std::cin and std::cout are bound together with magic it does not really matter though.

Initializing the random number generator should be done **once** in the application. So do it just after main() starts. There is no need to cast the result to unsigned. A lot of people think 0 is good here I still like using the macro NULL (the problem with NULL is that on crappy compilers it is not defined correctly for C++). To me the NULL conveys more information in that it is supposed to be a pointer not the number 0. Though with C++11 I am trying to use nullptr.

Using this technique for generating a random value will get a lot of fanatics complaining.

```
nComputerMove=rand()%(3)+1;
```

Personally for this problem I think its fine. But  a slightly better version would be:

```
 nComputerMove=(rand() / (RAND_MAX * 1.0)) * 3 + 1;
```

This makes the distribution slightly more even. Because 3 does not divide exactly into RAND_MAX your version has a slightly higher probability of being Rock 1/10922 than Scissors 1/10923 (assuming RAND_MAX of 32767). If you want to be really pedantic about it you would throw out any values greater than `RAND_MAX/3*3`. Then use mod 3.

Don't use this:

```
system("pause");
system("cls");
```

Comment: thank you :) I like the arrays idea and the way you print the results, ill fix my code soon with notes of everything you and Anton wrote.

Comment: Not always `1/10922` but rather `1/(RAND_MAX/3)`? On my computer, `RAND_MAX` is 2147483647.